# Как кешировать google maps

Tags: php, google-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В page insight 99 не хватает одного ругается что нужно сделать кеширование. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете управлять временем кеширования стороннего ресурса. Поэтому единственным решением является загрузка скрипта Google Maps на свой сервер, и подключение на сайт уже оттуда. Тогда вы сможете добиться любого времени кеширования и повысить оценку Pagespeed.

Чтобы скрипт не устарел, рекомендуется дважды в сутки его обновлять на своём сервере по crown.

Я делал плагин с этим функционалом на WordPress, работает на клиентских сайтах. Pagespeed Insights снимает своё замечание при таком подходе.

Comment: Не сильно помогло раньше требовало кеширования теперь простит еще gzip сжатие а он включен на сервере. Файл скрипта не имеет расширения

Comment: Не помогло, потому что вы не догадались переименовать локальный файл. В моём плагине он сохраняется под именем gmap.js. Я же говорю вам - решение рабочее.